# How to disable multiple clicking on the BottomNavigationView item not at all, but only on one fragment android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview

I have one `Activity` and two `Fragments`. I also have a `BottomNavigationView` added to navigate between these two fragments (for example, let it be `Fragment A` and `Fragment B`)

I know there is `setOnItemReselectedListener()` , so I wrote this `Extension` function:

```
fun BottomNavigationView.disableItemsReselected() {
    this.setOnItemReselectedListener {  }
}
```

...however, this function completely disables the ability to reselect the elements, but I need to make it so that the reselect is not available in `Fragment A`, but is available in `Fragment B`

How can I do that?

P.S.: my code of creating navController

```
fun AppCompatActivity.setupBottomNavigationView() {
    val navHostFragment =
        supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
    val navView = this.findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.nav_view)

    val navController = navHostFragment.navController

    navView.setupWithNavController(navController)
    navView.disableItemsReselected()
}
```

Comment: Are you using a navController? I've tried to create a test project and when I click the same bottomNav item it doesn't reload the fragment

Comment: @marcpetitvecino yes, i am using navController in my project

Comment: @marcpetitvecino i added code of how i create navController

Comment: So if I'm understanding this, the problem is that you press the already selected bottomNav item and it reloads the fragment, right?

Comment: @marcpetitvecino yes, and this happens on all Fragments, but I need to make this reloads, for example, only work if the user is in Fragment B

Comment: It's strange since as I told you, I built a test project with a simple bottomNav and I verified that the fragments do not reload when reselected, and I didn't add any code for that